Split a Polygon into multiple polygons dependent on land use category
I would like to divide a polygon, which represents the boundaries of a community, into several polygons depending on the percentage distribution of land use, for example settlement area, arable land, forest, etc.
I do have the boundaries as shapefile and the percentages of different land uses. I would like to color the polygon of the district based on the percentage shares in order to graphically show how much area is required for a photovoltaic open space system.
It is not about showing where the areas are located, but simply about vividly representing the relationships between the space requirements of different land use typologies.
Is there an add-on for this usecase or is there another way to perform this task?

How were you planning on determining the percentage distribution of land uses?  Do you have land use polygons, imagery, land use rasters, etc?

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user please take the [Tour]. The most frequent comments here ask "What have you tried?" and "Where are you stuck?" Asking for a pre-written solution to an uncommon problem is not generally going to produce an answer. I suggest you start down the road towards solving this yourself. There are an infinite number of ways to partition a polygon, so you probably what to determine how you would tackle this task manually, then see if you can automate that. If nothing else, you'd be able to generate screenshots to describe what you've tried, and where you're stuck.
